# how can I trim <br> tags using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

```
String s="<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />hello world!<br /><br /><br />";
s=s.replaceAll("<br /><br />", "<br />");
System.out.println(s);
//result: <br /><br /><br />hello world!<br /><br />
```

I want to get `<br />hello world!<br />`

how to do? thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = s.replaceAll ("(<br />)+", "<br />")
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `s = s.replaceAll(/(<br\s*\/?>)+/, "<br />");`. This should replace any number of `<br />`s by one.

Comment: I would change it in to /(<br \/?>)+/.replaceAll("<br />"); In case some of the <br> were not closed with /.

Comment: I tried `s=s.replaceAll("/(<br \\/>)+/", "<br />");`  and `s=s.replaceAll("/(<br \\/?>)+/", "<br />");` not working

Comment: @MPękalski That sounds good. I'll add it, it needs a check to ignore possible spaces as well, though.

Comment: @Zenofo With regular expressions, the regex should be at the start. I updated my post so you can use that code.

Comment: Updated regex to: `/(<br\s*\/?>)+/` to remove the requirement of ` /` in the `br` tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
/(<br \/>)+<br \/>/ -> "<br />"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
String healthyString = badString.replaceAll("(<br(.*?\\/?)>)+", "<br />");
```

or, according to your example...

```java
s = s.replaceAll("(<br(.*?\\/?)>)+", "<br />");
```

This expression will solve the problem. It matches all line-break combinations:
`<br>`, `<br/>`, and `<br />`.